Date as a string when exported to CSV
Can anyone help convert a Date in SQL Server 2016 to a string format, 'January 2024'? When I use the various methods below, the data in the CSV file still shows 01/01/2024.
FORMAT(COMPLETED_DATE, 'MMMM yyyy'))

or
datename(m,COMPLETED_DATE)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,COMPLETED_DATE) as varchar)



FORMAT( DATEFROMPARTS( 2024, 1, 1 ), 'MMM yyyy' ) won't ever return "01/0/2024" so something else is going wrong - What is the type of COMPLETED_DATE? Can you share your table-definitions and sample data?

How do you "export" your data

I noticed you said the output was 01/0/2024 which isn't a valid date at all - so something's afoot...

The data Type of the column 100% a date and the SQL above brings back the correct value, however when I export it I get a date and not a string.

I can confirm the CSV output of the column is 01/01/2024

I am exporting the data manually using SQL Server Management Studio & also get the same result when I export via Python 3.

Your first attempt gives me an error (extra right parathesis ())), however, if I correct that, both work fine: db<>fiddle I suggest you provide us with an actual [mre].

"I am exporting the data manually using SQL Server Management Studio" Right clicking the data grid and clicking "Save results as..."? Then the value in your datagrid was still 01/01/2024.

One hard lesson I've learned from almost 20 years I've been faffing around with SQL Server and related tooling is that CSV and MSSQL just don't mix: none of Microsoft's tooling ever did CSV "correctly" (whether that's RFC 4180 or the many Excel and MySQL-specific variants) - as of 2021-2024 the CSV+MSSQL situation is still pretty bad. I now recommend either using Excel's PowerQuery or use LinqPad with SqlClient and CSVWriter.

I've added an image to highlight the problem and changed the code to use getdate.
SELECT  convert(varchar(25),FORMAT(cast(getdate() as date), 'MMMM yyyy'), 120) Test

@LeeMurray the problem isn't the query, it's whatever you use to export the data. You still haven't explained that. And CSV is not an Excel format, it's nothing more than a formatted text file. Excel can store dates natively and display then in any way you want.

@LeeMurray manually using SQL Server Management Studio SSMS doesn't export data. If you use the Export Data task, you're actually creating and running an SSIS package that can be modified to export to whatever form you want. The best option would be Excel

You are correct; The CSV is showing June 2024. So therefore EXCEL must be doing a data conversion. Thank you all.

MMMM yyyy isn't a date either, it's just formatted text. That text could be any of the 31 possible days is in January. The unambiguous way of exporting dates as text, ie the one that no application will confuse, is YYYY-MM-DD (ISO8601).

@LeeMurray EXCEL must be doing a data conversion yes and no, and that's why you should export to Excel, not CSV. Excel has native support for dates and numbers. Text files like CSVs don't. Excel doesn't open CSVs, it imports them and converts anything the string values to numbers or dates. If you double-click on a CSV file the import is performed using the current user's locale settings. If you use the Data > From Text menu you can control the conversion. If you use Export Data in SSMS and export directly to Excel though, there's no conversion involved.

If you still want to export to a text file, you won't be able to open it by double-clicking without the default conversions. You'll have to use Data > From Text and specify that these fields are text instead of dates.

As I mentioned in several comments, if the text file has to be modified so it opens in Excel, it's better to just export to Excel. And even for CSVs, it's better to not use SSMS.
For example, with Python and Pandas exporting to either Excel or CSV is a simple call to to_excel or to_csv. In SQL Server 2017 and later, with Python support installed, one can use sp_execute_external_script to execute this.
This is a stored procedure I created to quickly export query results to CSV :
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ExportToCsv] (@sql nvarchar(max),@path nvarchar(max))
as
begin


EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python'
    , @script = N'
InputDataSet.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
'
    , @input_data_1 = @sql
    , @params=N'@csv_path nvarchar(max)'
    , @csv_path=@path;

END

For CSVs, we can force quoting of all fields through the quote parameter:
import csv

InputDataSet.to_csv(csv_path, index=False,quote=csv.ALL)

The parameter index=False prevents the export of the row number index as a separate column
The only change needed to export to Excel is to use to_excel, and get native decimals and dates without formatting problems.
The query itself is passed to @input_data_1 and loaded as a Pandas Dataframe in the script named InputDataSet. This means that the only code we really need to execute is
InputDataSet.to_excel(excel_path, index=False)


SOLVED - It's a dirty fix, but has got me out the hole. I just added a Text marker (") to the SQL, which stops EXCEL from formatting it as a date.
 SELECT  '"'+(convert(varchar(25),FORMAT(cast(getdate() as date), 'MMMM yyyy'), 120)) Test


The CONVERT( varchar(25), ) step is redundant because FORMAT already returns a varchar (or nvarchar) value.

You can avoid such "fixes" by using the correct file type. If you intend to use Excel so much you need to insert the text marker, you should be producing Excel files. And probably using anything other except SSMS to do it. What you ask is trivial to do with eg Python and Pandas, either through VS Code or sp_execute_external_script

I wouldn't call this a fix, even not a dirty one, it's just avoidable effort as pointed out in comments.

It is interesting you say Python & Pandas fix this, as I can verify that the same fault exists when using a DF in Pandas to publish an EXCEL sheet via XLWINGS. I agree df.to_csv fixes the problem in the CSV, but when you push the data to an EXCEL sheet, it reappears unless you change the column type to text.

@LeeMurray to_excel doesn't use XLWINGS. You didn't describe any problem in the question. That's how Excel works, period. If you want to display the date using a different style, you need to actually specify that numeric style. You can specify date styles in ExcelFile or you can use Pandas together with xlsxwriter to add formatting. It's interesting I use Pandas to both import a lot of Excel files with different formats and export millions of rows to different Excel formats every day.
